# Configurable Products: Replicate Product View in Custom Product List

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, products, product-list, rwd-theme

So I am using a child RWD theme, and adding some custom blocks to the tabbed section that goes under the single product view. One of those custom blocks is an essentially hijacked 'related products' blocks where I'm using

```
  $this->_itemCollection = $product->getRelatedProductCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setPositionOrder()
        ->addStoreFilter();
```

...to retrieve the collection. However I need to have the products in the 'related' section essentially mimic the single product view; they are all configurable products, so color/size attributes must be selectable and cause JS updates to the product display.

Additionally, add to cart must work via ajax like single product view.

This question has been asked before, and I've gone through a few tutorials, however they mostly seem to be outdated (magento 1.7 and below).

Does anyone know of a good solution/tutorial or even paid extension that would achieve this?